# Shopware6 API integrity constraints on nested entities

Tags: shopware

Tested on Shopware 6.3.5.1:

I'm trying to create a product via API together with its parent. That is necessary, because I can only iterate over variants in the other system.

As far as I can tell there's no conflict with the IDs or duplicates. Neither the product nor its parent already exist.

But when I do this:

```
POST https://somedomain.de/api/v3/_action/sync
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}
```

```json
{
  "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab": {
    "action": "upsert",
    "entity": "product",
    "payload": [
      {
        "id": "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab",
        "__code": "1111111189",
        "stock": 99,
        "taxId": "d390c2f211144543845dbf76fa69d17a",
        "cmsPageId": null,
        "deliveryTimeId": null,
        "manufacturerId": null,
        "visibilities": [
          {
            "id": "e24f994426246015347bba784ac69a97",
            "productId": "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab",
            "salesChannelId": "8e7c11e2540b4c71b521d5a59920e142",
            "visibility": 30
          }
        ],
        "unitId": null,
        "price": [
          {
            "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
            "net": 25,
            "gross": 29.75,
            "linked": true
          }
        ],
        "productNumber": "1111111189",
        "coverId": null,
        "translations": {
          "ce1df85b5f1c4eedbc532cbd34c57df6": {
            "name": "Converse black",
            "description": "Converse black"
          },
          "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b": {
            "name": "Converse black",
            "description": "Converse black"
          }
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "e90cf50735a0d6f69b2dbf599caa4954"
          },
          {
            "id": "a5b4753f41c8f4bedba1bf5954c961cb"
          }
        ],
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09"
          }
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "id": "cb9a886400616c215a588b13cb7c662b",
            "mediaId": "a7aabb5ff4dc3c99ba45724ec7477ffe"
          }
        ],
        "parent": {
          "id": "7a788255eab96bf51002829b3a6becf2",
          "__code": "1111111189",
          "stock": 99,
          "taxId": "d390c2f211144543845dbf76fa69d17a",
          "cmsPageId": null,
          "deliveryTimeId": null,
          "manufacturerId": null,
          "visibilities": [
            {
              "id": "8d5a7e2b2c02986a924eaf3d9504413c",
              "productId": "7a788255eab96bf51002829b3a6becf2",
              "salesChannelId": "8e7c11e2540b4c71b521d5a59920e142",
              "visibility": 30
            }
          ],
          "unitId": null,
          "price": [
            {
              "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
              "net": 25,
              "gross": 29.75,
              "linked": true
            }
          ],
          "productNumber": "converseblack",
          "coverId": null,
          "translations": {
            "ce1df85b5f1c4eedbc532cbd34c57df6": {
              "name": "Converse black",
              "description": "Converse black"
            },
            "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b": {
              "name": "Converse black",
              "description": "Converse black"
            }
          },
          "categories": [
            {
              "id": "e90cf50735a0d6f69b2dbf599caa4954"
            },
            {
              "id": "a5b4753f41c8f4bedba1bf5954c961cb"
            }
          ],
          "properties": [
            {
              "id": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09"
            }
          ],
          "media": [
            {
              "id": "cb9a886400616c215a588b13cb7c662b",
              "mediaId": "a7aabb5ff4dc3c99ba45724ec7477ffe"
            }
          ],
          "configuratorSettings": [
            {
              "optionId": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09",
              "id": "db3787abb8d6372e1997c144031ef1e2"
            }
          ]
        },
        "parentId": "7a788255eab96bf51002829b3a6becf2",
        "options": [
          {
            "id": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get as a response that the integrity constraint productId X saleschannelId in visibilities gets violated:

```json
{
  "success": false,
  "data": {
    "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab": {
      "result": [
        {
          "entities": [],
          "errors": [
            {
              "code": "0",
              "status": "500",
              "title": "Internal Server Error",
              "detail": "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `product_visibility` (`id`, `product_id`, `product_version_id`, `sales_channel_id`, `visibility`, `created_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [\"\\x8d\\x5a\\x7e\\x2b\\x2c\\x02\\x98\\x6a\\x92\\x4e\\xaf\\x3d\\x95\\x04\\x41\\x3c\", \"\\x7a\\x78\\x82\\x55\\xea\\xb9\\x6b\\xf5\\x10\\x02\\x82\\x9b\\x3a\\x6b\\xec\\xf2\", \"\\x0f\\xa9\\x1c\\xe3\\xe9\\x6a\\x4b\\xc2\\xbe\\x4b\\xd9\\xce\\x75\\x2c\\x34\\x25\", \"\\x8e\\x7c\\x11\\xe2\\x54\\x0b\\x4c\\x71\\xb5\\x21\\xd5\\xa5\\x99\\x20\\xe1\\x42\", 30, \"2021-02-22 11:36:18.099\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'zx\\x82U\\xEA\\xB9k\\xF5\\x10\\x02\\x82\\x9B:k\\xEC\\xF2-\\x0F\\xA9\\x1C\\x...' for key 'uniq.product_id__sales_channel_id'"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "extensions": []
    }
  },
  "extensions": []
}
```

Comment: Btw, if I remove the `visibilities` from the `parent` or the actual product it works. So it behaves like a XOR.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out, that it's possible to extract the nested entities into separate actions (that works):

```json
{
  "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab": {
    "action": "upsert",
    "entity": "product",
    "payload": [
      {
        "id": "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab",
        "__code": "1111111189",
        "stock": 99,
        "taxId": "d390c2f211144543845dbf76fa69d17a",
        "cmsPageId": null,
        "deliveryTimeId": null,
        "manufacturerId": null,
        "unitId": null,
        "price": [
          {
            "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
            "net": 25,
            "gross": 29.75,
            "linked": true
          }
        ],
        "productNumber": "1111111189",
        "coverId": null,
        "translations": {
          "ce1df85b5f1c4eedbc532cbd34c57df6": {
            "name": "Converse black",
            "description": "Converse black"
          },
          "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b": {
            "name": "Converse black",
            "description": "Converse black"
          }
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "e90cf50735a0d6f69b2dbf599caa4954"
          },
          {
            "id": "a5b4753f41c8f4bedba1bf5954c961cb"
          }
        ],
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09"
          }
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "id": "cb9a886400616c215a588b13cb7c662b",
            "mediaId": "a7aabb5ff4dc3c99ba45724ec7477ffe"
          }
        ],
        "parent": {
          "id": "7a788255eab96bf51002829b3a6becf2",
          "__code": "1111111189",
          "stock": 99,
          "taxId": "d390c2f211144543845dbf76fa69d17a",
          "cmsPageId": null,
          "deliveryTimeId": null,
          "manufacturerId": null,
          "unitId": null,
          "price": [
            {
              "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
              "net": 25,
              "gross": 29.75,
              "linked": true
            }
          ],
          "productNumber": "converseblack",
          "coverId": null,
          "translations": {
            "ce1df85b5f1c4eedbc532cbd34c57df6": {
              "name": "Converse black",
              "description": "Converse black"
            },
            "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b": {
              "name": "Converse black",
              "description": "Converse black"
            }
          },
          "categories": [
            {
              "id": "e90cf50735a0d6f69b2dbf599caa4954"
            },
            {
              "id": "a5b4753f41c8f4bedba1bf5954c961cb"
            }
          ],
          "properties": [
            {
              "id": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09"
            }
          ],
          "media": [
            {
              "id": "cb9a886400616c215a588b13cb7c662b",
              "mediaId": "a7aabb5ff4dc3c99ba45724ec7477ffe"
            }
          ],
          "configuratorSettings": [
            {
              "optionId": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09",
              "id": "db3787abb8d6372e1997c144031ef1e2"
            }
          ]
        },
        "parentId": "7a788255eab96bf51002829b3a6becf2",
        "options": [
          {
            "id": "a01a0380ca3c61428c26a231f0e49a09"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "e24f994426246015347bba784ac69a97": {
    "action": "upsert",
    "entity": "product_visibility",
    "payload": [
      {
        "id": "e24f994426246015347bba784ac69a97",
        "productId": "7508d64f832fb06b8f82f78963b280ab",
        "salesChannelId": "8e7c11e2540b4c71b521d5a59920e142",
        "visibility": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  "8d5a7e2b2c02986a924eaf3d9504413c": {
    "action": "upsert",
    "entity": "product_visibility",
    "payload": [
      {
        "id": "8d5a7e2b2c02986a924eaf3d9504413c",
        "productId": "7a788255eab96bf51002829b3a6becf2",
        "salesChannelId": "8e7c11e2540b4c71b521d5a59920e142",
        "visibility": 30
      }
    ]
  }
}
```